# HTTPS using Keystore Issue in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore

I am trying to call a Https service from Java which requires certificate for ssl.
Now, the https service which I am trying to invoke has created a keystore using the below command,

```
keytool -genkey -keystore abc.jks -dname "CN=test, OU=test, O=test, L=test, ST=test, C=IN" -alias testcert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365
```

Now, when I am trying to invoke the service using the above same keystore generated, I am getting exception as below,

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
```

I am using the below code for connecting to the https service,

```
char []passwKey = "passwd".toCharArray();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("abc.jks"), passwKey);
    KeyManagerFactory keyFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyFac.init(keyStore,passwKey);


    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(keyFac.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL("https://url").openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + responseCode);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you try to understand the difference between keystore/keymanager and truststore/trustmanager first ("keystore" means multiple things). You've used the keystore to initialise the keymanager whereas it should be used for the trustmanager in your situation. (In fact, you should not use the keystore of the server as a trustmanager directly, you should create a new keystore *without* private keys.)

Comment: Can you please provide me some link where I can understand this. I am new to ssl. I just want to try out basic level of secure http, I can change both the server side and client side keystore.

Comment: See the JSSE Reference Guide. Unless the server certificate is self-signed, you don't need a custom KeyManager or SSLContext at all.